# Paste format string or paste-with-replace

Tags: vim, emacs

In Vim, can I supply a format string, yank it, and paste it with formatted values in a range?.  An example in Python 2 would be:

> for i in range(1, 3): print "This is line %d" % i

If this is not possible in Vim, would it be so in Emacs, or another editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not completely clear to me what you want, but in Vim you could do something like this:

```
:for i in range(line('$')) | call append(i+i, printf("this is line %d:", i+1)) | endfor
```

The reason I use "`i+i`" is that, as lines are inserted into the buffer the line numbers change, and this corrects for that.  (If you have a different "starting point" in your range, your correction algorithm will have to be more complicated.)

Or if you want to modify the existing lines in the buffer instead:

```
:for i in range(1, line('$')) | call setline(i, printf("this is line %2d: %s", i, getline(i))) | endfor
```

Of course, if you don't want to change the buffer, but just print to the screen, use "echo" instead of "call" and remove the append() / setline() chunks from around the printf().

See:

```
:help :for
:help :call
:help :echo
:help range()
:help line()
:help append()
:help setline()
:help getline()
:help printf()
```

Comment: Perfect; thank you.  I apologize for not being concise, but your second code example did exactly what I wanted.  Since I'm new I cannot upvote, but I will when I can.

Comment: Of course, there's another, arguably simpler way to do it:  :%s/^/\=printf("This is line %d: ", line('.'))/

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs try:

```
M: (dotimes (i 3) (insert (format "This is line %2d.\n" (1+ i))))
```

Here `M:` stands for `eval-expression`

Comment: For those who don't know Emacs: It's `Alt + :`